# MacOS Ventura - Completely disable multiple spaces and mission control

Tags: macos, desktop, osx-spaces, macos-ventura

I have a Mac running Ventura and two monitors. I find the use of Spaces or multiple desktops distracting given that I have adequate screen real estate for the way I work. (Disclosure: I'm a Windows user as well, and while they have their equivalent to Spaces, I hate that as well.)

I just want to turn the whole thing off and manage all my apps on one desktop/space, spread across my laptop screen and my external monitor. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You don't need to 'switch it off' just don't use it. Make sure 'displays have separate Spaces' is off too.

Comment: But I want to switch it off. This is something that should be disableable forcefully, so that I don't accidentally trigger it with some silly gesture that I don't care about as a power user.